# Spring WebFlux Security JWT?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

Is there an example of `JWT security` with `Spring 5 WebFlux Security`?  Or has JWT been replaced with something else?

Alternatively, what would be the best security mechanism for `WebFlux` and `Angular 2` application if I don't want to use an external authentication provider (e.g. Google etc)?